# How to handle QPropertyAnimation for a large number of widgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qpropertyanimation

I want to have many colored dots constantly move across a background. (Description of code below): A PolkaDot widget is constructed with a random color, size, position, and duration. The QPropertyAnimation moves the widget across the screen from left to right, restarting at a new height when the animation ends. 100 PolkaDot widgets are constructed in the Background widget, which is enough to make it appear like tons of new dots are constantly rushing in from the left side of the screen.

However, the 100 property animations seem to consume a lot of CPU power, causing it to slow down and look un-smooth. Is there another way to achieve a similar result? Try running the code below.

```
import sys, random
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

colors = [QColor('#f00'), QColor('#00f'), QColor('#0f0'), QColor('#ff0'),
          QColor('#fff'), QColor('#ff6000'), QColor('#6b00ff'), QColor('#f0f')]

class PolkaDot(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setFixedSize(50, 50)
        self.color = random.choice(colors)
        self.r = random.randrange(5, 22)
        self.move(random.randrange(w), random.randrange(h))
        self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self, b'pos')
        self.anim.finished.connect(self.run)
        self.anim.setDuration(random.randrange(3000, 9000))
        self.anim.setStartValue(QPoint(self.x() - (w + 60), self.y()))
        self.anim.setEndValue(QPoint(w + 60, self.y()))
        self.anim.start()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        qp.setBrush(self.color)
        qp.setPen(QPen(self.color.darker(130), self.r / 5))
        qp.drawEllipse(QPoint(25, 25), self.r, self.r)

    def run(self):
        y = random.randrange(h)
        self.anim.setDuration(random.randrange(3000, 9000))
        self.anim.setStartValue(QPoint(-60, y))
        self.anim.setEndValue(QPoint(w + 60, y + random.randrange(-50, 50)))
        self.anim.start()


class Background(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(window)
        polka_dots = [PolkaDot(self) for i in range(100)]
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: #000')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry()
    w, h = window.width(), window.height()
    gui = Background()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You can’t ping moderators just by naming them; I only saw the comment here because it was flagged. Please use a custom moderator flag on a post to request moderator feedback on our actions. Sorry, that specific account was removed for moderation reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I sort of found a solution. For some reason, creating the dots in the background widget's paint event and calling repaint() on QTimer.timeout() to update the XY coordinates is much more efficient than using QPropertyAnimation.

```
tick = 24

class Dot(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randrange(-w - 60, 0)
        self.randomize()

    def randomize(self):
        self.color = random.choice(colors)
        self.r = random.randrange(5, 22)
        self.y = random.randrange(h)
        self.x_speed = random.randrange(3000, 9000)
        self.y_speed = random.randrange(-50, 50)

    def move(self):
        self.x += w * tick / self.x_speed
        self.y += self.y_speed * tick / self.x_speed
        if self.x > w:
            self.x = -60
            self.randomize()


class Background(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(window)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: #000')
        self.dots = [Dot() for i in range(150)]
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(tick)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.animate)
        self.timer.start()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        for dot in self.dots:
            qp.setBrush(dot.color)
            qp.setPen(QPen(dot.color.darker(130), dot.r / 5))
            qp.drawEllipse(QPoint(dot.x, dot.y), dot.r, dot.r)

    def animate(self):
        for d in self.dots:
            d.move()
        self.repaint()
```